# Get latest entry using GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm pulling out some conversations from my database. They are being grouped by the **user_from** column.

As of now, it outputs the oldest message. I want it to show the *newest* message.

What is the most  simple way of doing this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (`mail`)
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `mail`.`user_from`
JOIN `users_info` ON `users_info`.`user_id` = `mail`.`user_from`
WHERE `user_to` =  '1'
GROUP BY `user_from`
ORDER BY `mail`.`date` desc
```

mail table

[image]

user table (snippet)

[image]

This is the current working code. The *SecretAgent* sent a message **newer** than *Mail from the agency* which it should be showing instead
[image]

Comment: @xQbert Why?, the newest message is the one with the max date

Comment: Guessing that mail as an ID, why don't you order by `mail.id desc`? or are the emails inserted from different places and the higher id is not necessary the newest email?

Comment: That won't do the trick, it still selects the *oldest* one

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for this commment: "This may (probably will) still produce unreliable results. MySQL permits cols in the SELECT which are not also in the GROUP BY, ofen resulting in indeterminate values for other cols"

Comment: @Lamak yes it was greatly and totally, totally duh wrong..

Comment: @PatrickReck What do you actually want as a result?. Just because MySQL allows to group by a column and select all other columns, doesn't mean that the results are reliable. What is your expected result?

Comment: Please post your table schema.  More info is needed to do this properly.

Comment: @Lamak I want it to take all the messages sent to the user, sort it by the users who sent them, showing the newest one for each user. **Tables have been added to the post**

Comment: +1 this question is interesting..

Comment: This question should not have this many upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL is unfortunately very lenient about the contents of the `GROUP BY` clause, which produces unreliable results unless you include all columns in the `GROUP BY`. It is never recommended to `SELECT *` in a join query, but we'll leave that for now. What you need to do is perform a subquery join which gets the most recent message for the user by date, joined against the rest of the columns.

```
SELECT 
  /* Don't actually do this. Be explicit about columns and assign aliases where their names collide */
  users.*,
  users_info.*,
  mail.*
FROM
  `users`
  JOIN `mail` ON `users`.`id` = `mail`.`user_from`
  JOIN `users_info` ON `users_info`.`user_id` = `mail`.`user_from`
  /* Joined subquery gets most recent message from each user */
  JOIN (
    SELECT  user_from, MAX(date) AS date
    FROM mail
    WHERE user_to = '1'
    GROUP BY user_from
    /* Joined back to the main mail table on user_from and date */
  ) most_recent ON mail.user_from = most_recent.user_from AND mail.date = most_recent.date
  WHERE `user_to` =  '1'
```

**Edit** Updated to show all most recent senders rather than only one.

Comment: This seems to work when running it in PHPMyAdmin. Now I'll just dive into the CodeIgniter docs and see how I can make this work using Active Records. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @njk Just hoping to stay active - I don't answer too many anymore. some seem to have "retired" at 100k. I'm maybe 3 days away...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So retirement party?

Comment: @njk Not while I'm still [achingly close to the top 100](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/541091?sort=reputationchange#541091). Maybe then I'll hide away and troll meta.